# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)...(1+a^{2^n})$?

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)...(1+a^{2^n})$$

Where $|a|<1$.

Comment: Hint: write a few terms for small $n$.

Comment: Multiply by $\frac{1-a}{1-a}$.

Comment: $\times \frac {1-a}{1-a}$. Good Luck!

Comment: You can see what happens in the finite case when $a=10$, since $11\times 101=1111$ and $11 \times 101\times 10001=11111111$ etc.

Comment: @Henry $|a|<1$ ${}$

Comment: Thanks, that helped me ! Now all terms are in the form $(1-x)(1+x) = (1-x^2)$

Comment: @lonestudent which is why I said "finite".  Doing it for $a=0.1$ so $1.1\times 1.01=1.111$ and $1.1 \times 1.01\times 1.0001=1.1111111$ etc. is slightly less intutitive

Comment: @Pete  By the way, If you don't make an any effort, the "do my homework" questions are not a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1-a)f=(1-a)(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^8)...(1+a^{2^n})=(1-a^{2^{n+1}})$$
Use $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2$ sucsessively to get
$$f_n=\frac{1-a^{2^{n
+1}}}{1-a}.$$
As $|a|<1$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n= \frac{1}{1-a}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps interesting even though a valid answer already exists:

Since every positive integer has a unique representation as the sum of
distinct powers of $2$ (that is, a unique binary expansion), you see that $$(1+a)(1+a^2)\dots(1+a^{2^n})=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}a^k.$$(Give a formal proof of that by induction.) So  the limit is $\sum a^k=1/(1-a)$.